# How do I track 2 lights in real time with a camera and send it to a phone in Unity?

Tags: unity, camera, unity-networking

I am trying to track 2 lights and send that data to Unity for VR controller tracking. How do I get started? Do I make an app that communicates with Wifi or something? And how do I detect the lights? OpenCV seems complicated. I will have a 3DOF IMU in the controllers and a big orb so it will be kind of like a Playstation Move but with a normal webcam. I will use the lights combined with the rotational data to figure out the position.

---

For other people to know, I will use the Processing video library to recognize the lights and OSCP5 to send it to Unity.

Comment: What can you tell us about these lights? What kind of tracking do you need to do with them? How does this relate to the gameplay of your game? Right now the question gives very little context for a reader who doesn't already know about your project, so we might be liable to give you very ill-suited answers unless you **edit your question** to explain your goals in more detail.

Comment: So is your question how to track a coloured ball in a webcam video stream? Or how to transmit data from the IMU in the controller to your computer, over something like Bluetooth/Wifi/etc? Those are two different questions and will have very different answers.

Comment: I already have the rotation being sent over to the phone but I will probably need to send it to the computer to help figure out the position. So I need to track the position with the computer and send to phone.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few high-level tasks:

- Detect The position of the lights relative to the camera
- Convert that location into "world" space
- Transmit it to the device
- Do it all **Fast**

Looking at each in turn:

#### Detect the position of the lights

I'm not entirely clear what hardware will be doing this? Desktop PC with a webcam?

Assuming so, then yes, you're going to need to do some image analysis. OpenCV is a solid option although there are alternatives. Many professional positional controllers

Your biggest issue is that a single camera *almost* doesn't have enough information to locate an object in 3D space.

Let's say you detect the object is 15° left of center on the °0 above horizontal.

There are an infinite number of points which meet those criteria, all on a line pointing out from your camera.

So you also need to detect *where* on the line that is.

Some systems like Oculus use multiple cameras, others (like Kinect) us a depth-sensor.

You *could* potentially factor in the known size of the controller but you'd likely need to calibrate on a per-webcam basis as each lens will have a slightly different FoV and optical properties.

If using multiple cameras, you need to know their position relative to each other, then cross-reference the "lines" you get from each. The place they [almost] intersect is where your controller is.

#### Convert to world space

So now you've got a Vector2 relative to a couple of cameras [or single camera w/ depth info].

You now need to convert that into the same worldspace as the VR simulation.

To do that you'll need some basic trigonometry and a way of reading the VR world coordinate system [so you know how to map/transform the position information]

#### Transmit to device

As to how to get the data back to the device running the VR simulation... It depends what the webcam is connected to.

Your default option should always be a wired connected. LAN is far better throughput than Wifi and has lower inherent latency. Custom cables (like a Serial cable) would potentially be even faster. Likewise you might be able to communicate over a USB protocol at an acceptable rate.

#### Do it all **Fast**

So the big issue is latency. The longer the delay between controller movement and response in the simulation, the less immersive/believable it will be.

Ideally you want to have latencies from movement to pixel updates on the order of 10s of milliseconds.

Whatever process you pick needs to be iterating rapidly and each of the above steps is going to require some level of processing/waiting, so you need to steal as much time and performance as you can at each step of the process.

Comment: Yes, I will be using a camera and PC connected to the internet, because it should just need to send 6 numbers, the rotation and position (or 7 because quaternion is 4). To track the distance away from the camera I will see the distance between the leds. I would probably have to calibrate the distances like a normal VR headset does.